# Python, Iterate through a list sending batches of 100 records at a time to an API, then appending results to another list

Tags: python, hash-map

I have a list of 9000 dictionaries and I am sending them to an API in batches of 100 (limit of the API). The API returns the list of 100 dictionaries just expanded with more key/value pairs. So both lists look something like this:

```
[
{Key1:Val1, Key2:Val2},
{Key1:Val3, Key2:Val4},
...
]
```

and returns:

```
[
{Key1:Val1, Key2:Val2,Key3:Val1, Key4:Val4},
{Key1:Val3, Key2:Val4,Key3:Val1, Key4:Val4},
...
]
```

Now, I have to create a list that has all 9000 returned dictionaries in them, because the original input receives a batch of 9000 so it needs to output them all at once as well. I have accomplished this with the following code:

```
dict_list = [This is the list with 9000 dicts]
batch_list = []
return_list = []

for i in dictlist:
    batch_list.append(i)
    if len(batch_list)  == 100:
        api_batch = API_CALL_FUNCTION(batch_list)
        for j in api_batch:
            return_list.append(j)
        batch_list.clear()
    else:
        continue
if batch_list:
    api_batch = API_CALL_FUNCTION(batch_list)
    for k in api_batch:
        return_list.append(k)
```

This code does what I want it to, but I really don't like the nested for loop and I'm sure there's probably a more efficient way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to append the returned API list directly to return_list:

```
dict_list = [This is the list with 9000 dicts]
batch_list = []
return_list = []

for i in dictlist:
    batch_list.append(i)
    if len(batch_list)  == 100:
        return_list.append(API_CALL_FUNCTION(batch_list))
        batch_list.clear()

if batch_list:
    return_list.append(API_CALL_FUNCTION(batch_list))
```

and your else clause is un-needed.

You should also explore slicing the dictlist instead of iterating through each one.
You can call dictlist[0:100] and it will return a list containing the first 100 elements. dictlist[100:200] will return the next chunck, etc.

Hope this helped! Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty definitive post by Ned Batchelder on how to chunk a list over on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/4029014

The Python3 version looks like this:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

So you could process your list using this structure:

```
MAX_API_BATCH_SIZE = 100

for batch in chunks(dict_list, MAX_API_BATCH_SIZE):
    batch_done = API_CALL_FUNCTION(batch)
```

Note that there is already a method on lists for concatenating a second list: it's [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=extend#more-on-lists). So you can say:

```
    return_list.extend(batch_done)
```

Your code is obviously example code, which is a violation of how CodeReview works (so this question probably should have been asked on SO directly). Regardless, it should be in a function either way:

```
MAX_API_BATCH_SIZE = 100

def process_records_through_api(records, batch_size=None):
    """ Process records through the XYZ api. Return resulting records. """

    batch_size = (MAX_API_BATCH_SIZE if batch_size is None or batch_size < 1 
                  else batch_size)
    result = []

    for batch in chunks(records, batch_size):
        result.extend(api_function(batch))

    return result
```